# Inserting foreign key from building association with given schema in single transaction

Tags: elixir, schema, ecto

I have a schema `exchange_accounts` and `user_profile`
`user_profile` has a foreign_key column `exchange_accounts_id` which is referenced from `exchange_accounts` schema. I want to insert data in `user_profile` table for which I need to associate `exchange_accounts_id` to primary key column of `exchange_accounts` table.

I have `create_user_profile` function
i tried it using `Ecto.Multi.run`
Now basically i am not understanding building association between the two.

```
def create_user_profile(profile_info, dealer_id) do
   Ecto.Multi.new()
    |> Ecto.Multi.run(:exchange, fn %{exchange: exchange} -> Ecto.build_assoc(exchange, :user_profile)
    |> Ecto.Multi.insert(:user, UserProfile.changeset(%UserProfile{}, profile_info))
    |> Ecto.Multi.merge(fn %{user: user} ->
      bank_detail =
        Ecto.build_assoc(user, :bank_details)
        |> BankDetails.changeset(profile_info)

      Ecto.Multi.new()
      |> Ecto.Multi.insert(:bank_detail, bank_detail)
    end)
```

i want to do it before inserting data into `user_profile` table
And  i tried doing it using `Ecto.Multi.run`but its not working.

the result should be the association should be built between both tables and data should be inserted.
whenevr iam trying to run it its not going iside that unction only. i am not understanding where I am wrong and using `Ecto.Multi.run` is correct or not.

Answer (score 1):

`Ecto.Multi.run/3/5` by itself won't do anything, you still need to execute any operations inside the `fn/2` you pass it. This function needs to return either `{:ok, val}` for what you deem a successful operation or `{:error, val}` if you consider the operation failed, so that Ecto knows if it should rollback or not the whole transaction.

From > Ecto 3 (if I'm not mistaken), Multi `insert`, `update`, etc, can also accept a `fn/1` where the argument will be the Map of multi operations so far.

So you should probably change this:
`|> Ecto.Multi.run(:exchange, fn %{exchange: exchange} -> Ecto.build_assoc(exchange, :user_profile)`

to:

`|> Ecto.Multi.insert(:exchange, fn(_) -> Ecto.build_assoc(exchange, :user_profile) end)`

or keep the run, but do:

```
Ecto.build_assoc(exchange, :user_profile)
|> Repo.insert()
```

And then on the user insert, use the `:exchange` value to place it in your user_profile.

```
|> Ecto.Multi.insert(:user, fn(%{exchange: exchange}) ->
  # now you have access to the `exchange` operation result from the previous step
  UserProfile.changeset(%UserProfile{}, profile_info)
end)
```

You can also run all of this as regular code inside a `Repo.transaction/1` by doing the regular `Repo.insert`, etc, inside of the `fn` closure passed to it.
Multi allows you to explicitly separate each operation, and access each of them in each following step, do other things that may or may not change if you deem the transaction successful (even if not related to DB operations) or not, and return successfully or with the failed operation, etc, along with passing the Multi structure around to add other stuff through `Multi.merge`.

Comment: ```Ecto.Multi.run``` function is not working well in this case..its not building association only

Comment: @RadhikaPatil I never actually used `build_assoc`, so without knowing the errors you're running into it's kinda hard to know what is going wrong.